# Date as Array Element in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a list of dates and corresponding numerical values I'd like to parse into an array, but I can't seem to find a method to place the date strings as an array element.  For example, using 3 numerical values, a minimal idea of what I'm trying is

```
data_date = '08/15/2003';
num1 = 56;
num2 = 23;
num3 = 2;

array = [data_date, num1, num2, num3];
```

A row in the desired array would look like

```
08/15/2003,56,23,2
```

To be specific, I'm writing this array to a file, so the above row is really the desired formatting in a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cell array](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) is what you need.

```
data_date = '08/15/2003';
num1 = 56;
num2 = 23;
num3 = 2;
array = {data_date, num1, num2, num3};
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of MATLAB, you could also use [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) for this.

```
t = table({'08/15/2003'; '08/16/2003'}, [56; 57], [23; 24], [2; 3]);
writetable(t, 'tmp.csv')
```